# Interaction of particles with a spectrum of waves, relativistic equation of motion

Tags: special-relativity, astrophysics, dimensional-analysis, plasma-physics

I have to work with a poorly documented code, that simulates the interaction of particles with a spectrum of waves. The previous author has made the equations of motion dimensionless by using the following method.

The equations of motion for the ions are
$$
\frac{d(\gamma \boldsymbol{\beta})}{dt} = \frac{e}{mc}\left( \mathbf{E} + \boldsymbol{\beta} \times \mathbf{B} \right), \tag{1}
$$
where
$$
\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}}. \tag{2}
$$

The dimensionalized ones are expressed as
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{\tilde{v}}}{d \tilde{t}} = - \frac{1}{\gamma} \frac{d \gamma}{d\tilde{t}} \mathbf{\tilde{v}} + \delta \tilde{\mathbf{E}} + \tilde{\mathbf{v}} \times \left( \hat{\mathbf{e}}_z + \delta \tilde{B} \; \hat{\mathbf{e}}_y \right) \tag{3}
$$
with
$$
\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + (v_A/c)^2 \tilde{v}^2}} . \tag{4}
$$
We also have that
$$\frac{d\gamma}{dt} = \frac{\gamma^3}{c^2} \mathbf{v} \cdot \frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} \; \; \Rightarrow \; \; \frac{d\gamma}{d\tilde{t}} = \left[ \left( \frac{c}{\gamma v_A} \right)^2 + \tilde{v}^2 \right]^{-1} \gamma \delta \tilde{E} \; \tilde{v}_x . \tag{5}
$$

We will drop the tilde symbols for convenience, since all equations are non-dimensional from now on. Then, the equations of motion become
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dv_x}{dt} & = \left( \frac{1}{\gamma} - f v_x^2 \right) \delta E + \frac{1}{\gamma} v_y - \frac{\delta B}{\gamma} v_z \tag{6a} \\
\frac{dv_y}{dt} & = - \frac{1}{\gamma} v_x - f \delta E v_x v_y \tag{6b} \\
\frac{dv_x}{dt} & =   \frac{\delta B}{\gamma} v_x - f \delta E v_x v_z \tag{6c}
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
f \equiv \left[ \left( \frac{c}{\gamma v_A} \right)^2 + \tilde{v}^2 \right]^{-1}. \tag{7}
$$

The parameters used for the normalization are:

Using quantities such as

1. r$_{0}$ (length): skin depth, $v_{A}/ \Omega_{c} = c/ \Omega_{p}$
2. m$_{0}$ (mass): ion mass, m$_{i}$,
   m$_{0}$ = m$_{p}$
3. t$_{0}$ (time): inverse gyrofrequency, $1/ \Omega_{c}$, $t_{0} = 1/\Omega_{c}$
4. v$_{0}$ (velocity): alfven speed, $v_{A}$, $v_{0} = v_{A}$
5. B$_{0}$ (magnetic field): $B_{0}$
6. E$_{0}$ (electric field): $v_{A}*B_{0}/c$
7. E$_{0}$ = $v_{A}*B_{0}/c$

Can someone explain the thought process? I am especially confused on how from the first to third equation he went from $\vec{B} \ to  \ (\hat{e}_{z} + \delta B \hat{e}_{y})$. Did he assume no magnetic field in the $\hat{e}_{x}$ direction and normalized by Bz?

Also how did he get the expression for $\frac{d \gamma}{d\tilde{t}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did he assume no magnetic field in the $\hat{e}_{x}$ direction and normalized by $B_{z}$?

Yes, that seems to be what was done, thus why the z-direction is only the unit vector.

> Also how did he get the expression for $\tfrac{ d \gamma }{ dt }$

Start with Equation 3 and do the inner product with $\mathbf{v}$.  The cross-product terms at the end all drop out as $\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{A}$ is always orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}$.  Then combine the terms with $\tfrac{ d \gamma }{ dt }$ on the left-hand side and factor it out to divide by the multiplier terms.  It looks as though the electric field is only along the x-direction too.  The rest is just some algebra.